# Why is this statement with bitwise operators the same as this if statement?

Tags: c, if-statement, bitwise-operators, branch-prediction

I was reading this question [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array?rq=1) and the best answer provided by 
Mysticial. The answer does a great job of explaining what is happening and why and also says this:

> So what can be done?
>
> If the compiler isn't able to optimize the branch into a conditional
>   move, you can try some hacks if you are willing to sacrifice
>   readability for performance.
>
> Replace:

```
 if (data[c] >= 128)
     sum += data[c];
```

> with:

```
int t = (data[c] - 128) >> 31; 
sum += ~t & data[c];
```

> This eliminates the branch and replaces it with some bitwise
>   operations.

What exactly is this code doing and why is it equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It first converts the comparison to subtraction with 128.

Then the sign of the result (whether subtracting went below 128) is expanded to either all zeroes or all ones, which is `and`ed to the value being added, zeroing it out if the result of the subtraction was negative.